# org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have this piece of code:

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

new Path("s3://bucket/key").getFileSystem(new Configuration())
```

When I run it locally I get the following exception:

```
No FileSystem for scheme "s3"
org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
```

However, when I run it on EMR using spark-shell this works:

```
scala> new Path("s3://bucket/key").getFileSystem(new Configuration())
res0: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem = com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem
```

What am I supposed to add to my sbt file in order to include `com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem` in my project? I know s3a:// works, but I'd like to use s3:// both in local tests and in the EMR application.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the URLs to match, try setting in your spark jobs

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
```

This says "use the S3A FS for s3 urls".

Comment: Thank you so much! this is what I was missing.